# Javascript - accessing single name value pair not working

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me why this is not working?

```
var fieldsValid = {
    registerUserName: false,
    registerEmail: false,
    registerPassword: false,
    registerConfirmPassword: false
};

function showState () {
    var str = "<p>registerUserName: " +  fieldsValid[registerEmail] + "</p>" ;
    document.getElementById('showstate').innerHTML = str;
}

showState();
```

There is no output into my div.

Comment: Protip: If you had looked in your browsers console it would have helpfully told you: *registerEmail is not defined*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use quotes around the property name because otherwise, `registerEmail` is treated as a variable containing the property name, not a property name:

```
var str = "<p>registerUserName: " +  fieldsValid['registerEmail'] + "</p>" ;
```

Or use the `.` syntax without quotes:

```
var str = "<p>registerUserName: " +  fieldsValid.registerEmail + "</p>" ;
```

[MDN Working With Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)s is a good resource, relevant to this.

For future debugging, observe the console (F12) in your browser.

Comment: and as a troubleshooting technique: `console.log(str)` after `var str...`

Comment: @jcollum: Much better to learn to use the debugger built into every modern browser. :-)

Comment: Nah, it's not as cut and dry as that. I usually feel like I've failed to understand my code if I have to debug it. Logging is faster.

Comment: I prefer the debugger to logging since it's gives me more flexibility like inspectors and ability to rerun code.

Comment: @jcollum: I usually feel I'm not done with my code until I've single-stepped it and made sure it doesn't just *seem* to work.

Comment: Really? That's so slow. I feel like my iterations are much faster with logging -- just starting up the debugger in node takes a good long while.

Answer (score -2):

Let's say you have someObject.
someObject[johndoe] Returns the item in someObject that has johndoe's value (since here it is a variable) as index.

Comment: @Ejay Sure I am -_-" johndoe is a variable here, like registerEmail for him

Comment: I want to say that I meant that johndoe is an undefined variable

Comment: i think you could rephrase your answer. It looks like a word puzzle to me.

Comment: @Ejay Is it better now? ù.ù